# No clan chest after playing the team battle

Tags: clash-royale

I want to ask that my clan had been finished playing the team battle and I didn't receive the chest ( It was already at 10/10). Is it that we need to wait until the team battle to be finished to get the chest, or it is a glitch

Answer (score 2):

According to [this wikia page](http://clashroyale.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Chest) a Clan Chest will be available for opening after collecting all crowns. There isn't any cooldown to open it.

Another condition to get rewards from a Clan Chest is that you must have joined your clan before the Clan Chest Event started. Otherwise you'll have to wait for the next Clan Chest Event.

So, the reasons that you can't collect your rewards from the Clan Chest are:

- You joined your clan after a Clan Chest Event started.
- You left your clan and joined back.

Comment: Do you have to have contributed at least one 2v2 win to get to open the chest?